# How to use increment and decrement operators in python dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

There are functions/operators like `++`, `--` in C language. How to use the above function in python dataframe?

Comment: Simply `+=1` and `-=1` assuming you mean `i++` and not `++i`

Answer (score 2):

There are no `++` or `--` operations in python. Instead you can use `+=1` or `-=1`. There are other also like `*=`, `/=`, `%=`, `**=` and lot more. You can take a look at https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_operators.asp for more information.